# How does IP Masquerading send packages back to the original device on inbound connections?

Tags: networking, iptables, routing

I established a WireGuard Point-to-Site connection following this Tutorial: https://www.procustodibus.com/blog/2020/11/wireguard-point-to-site-config/#configure-routing-on-host-b

The connection itself works, so that is not my problem.
In the Tutorial he first activates routing on the device. Afterwards he puts up an iptables-Rule. This rules masquerades all the packages coming in on the WireGuard interface.

I have three devices:

-the origin in one network

-the gateway and the target in another.

So when the origin sends packages to the target device, and after entering the target network, they leave the WireGuard-Tunnel and get masqueraded. When the target answers, it arrives back on the original device. I'm not sure how the answer process works.

But how does this (let's call it De-Masquerading) work?

I didn't find anything in the man-pages and everything i find online revolves around NAT on outbound connections, not an inbound connection like mine.

Does it work the same way as NAT? It establishes a routing table and saves the target ip-adress and the corresponding port and sends the packages back to the original device, if it matches?

If you could cite your answer that would be great. I'm working on my thesis, so if possible i would like to cite a documentation or similar things instead of a StackExchange answer.

Comment: the `MASQUERADE` target is source NAT, like the `SNAT` target, and yes, it keeps a translation table. It doesn't really matter if it's the source or destination address that gets translated, the device doing it has to keep tabs on what addresses it changes, exactly so that return traffic also works. (And especially TCP requires getting replies from the same address the outgoing packets were sent to.)